# Have SVN function as a Second (remote) repo to push to with Git?

Tags: git, svn

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to have a SVN repo as a remote (secondary) repo to push commits to? I want Git repo to be my origin repo.

I prefer Git and have my own private Git hosting and the company I work for has SVN repo. I want everything I do go to my Git repo first until I'm ready to push the all the changes to client's SVN. Let's consider I only want to push to/pull from SVN's trunk and don't need to worry about other branches/tags.

How do I go about this? I need to know:

1. How to add an SVN repo as a remote to my Git local repo?
2. How to pull/push changes from the remote SVN repo?

Again, I want to stress that I want to have my own private Git (hosted) repo as the origin.

Comment: Just so we know where you're starting from, have you looked at [git-svn](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html)?

Comment: Yes. And I have used it to have SVN as my main/origin repo to push to/pull from. I am just wondering if it's doable to have SVN as secondary/remote repo.

Comment: @MichalM there's no way you could have had it as your "origin". Running `git push` with a repo cloned from svn accomplishes nothing (unless of course you've defined your own origin, in which case you've just answered your own question)

Comment: @Chris Yes, you're correct. Of course if I cloned SVN repo it wouldn't end up as my origin. Too late to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a "secondary" svn repository. I had the same problem a few weeks ago and I used several tutorials :

- http://flavio.castelli.name/howto_use_git_with_svn (on git-svn)
- http://jpz-log.info/archives/2009/09/16/start-in-git-push-to-subversion-then-work-with-git-svn/ (on how to deal with a remote svn repository with git)
- http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial (another complete tutorial)

So basically, I did my work on my local master branch, often pushed to origin (git repository) and sometimes pushed on the svn server (company repository).

In your `.git/config`, you should have something like this :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = your-url-to-the-git-repository
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = your-url-to-the-svn-repository
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

I also had a local "svn" branch but that may not be needed. In order to push my work, I had :

```
git push origin         # push to remote git repo
git svn dcommit         # push to remote svn repo
```

If you are not sure when you are pushing, use the `--dry-run` option :

```
git svn dcommit --dry-run     # check that you are pushing to the right branch
```

You can get more details on the usual workflow in the [tutorials](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped a lot, especially the 2nd link. I ran into a problem though. Interestingly enough the problem is not with git-svn! Problem lays in the origin git repo. It gets very, very messy. After I dcommit changes to svn, commit hashes change on my local git repo and I can no longer push changes to my private git repo as it requires pulling first. Pull causes a merge (no conflicts) that causes [the mess](http://d.pr/wrHa). Any chances to avoid this? I think I understand what's happening here and it may be unavoidable, but have to ask the question.

Comment: Yeah I had something weird happening too, which is why I decided to create a local "svn" branch. In that branch, I pulled/rebased from local master and remote svn branch. A possible workflow is explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241898/is-a-bidrectional-git-svn-sync-both-writable-possible

Answer (score 0):

> You can have Google Code act as a stable read-only Subversion mirror
>   of a Git project. In this model, patches are first applied to the
>   central Git repository and exported to Google Code later.
>
> Instead of merely providing a link to your repository, why not widen
>   your audience with just a handful of commands? Open up your Git-hosted
>   project to all Subversion users, whose patches can be integrated via
>   Git.

Of course this can also be used with non-Google Code SVN repos.

https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit